# ERROR com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureParser - syntax error: mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {FEATURE_TAGS, FEATURE}

Tags: karate

I am trying to run the automation test cases from runner file but the execution fails to start due to the following error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKmjs.png)

If you take a look at the attached screen prints, the project does not contain any feature file with that name (ACC45SOAP-Injury.feature). Can anyone tell me why am I experiencing this issue?

[Feature file package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBsO0.png)

Comment: please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi Peter. Here is the link to the issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/977#issue-530113471

Thank you.

Comment: I closed the issue because you DID NOT follow the instructions. try again